# Batch conversion of multiple numpy arrays into pandas DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, matrix

The following script converts multiple square matrices into pandas DataFrames, first manually, then as a loop function, plus labels their rows and columns identically.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from numpy.random import rand

A1 = rand(3,3)
A2 = A1*2
A3 = A1*3 #example square matrices, no math pattern implied

labels = ['a','b','c']
```

Manual conversion:

```
A1 = pd.DataFrame(A1, index=labels, columns=labels)
A2 = pd.DataFrame(A2, index=labels, columns=labels)
A3 = pd.DataFrame(A2, index=labels, columns=labels)
```

Batch conversion (loop):

```
def batch_df(l):
    ll = []
    for A in l:
        A_ = pd.DataFrame(A, index=labels, columns=labels)
        ll.append(A_)
    return ll 

ll = batch_df([A1, A2, A3])
print(len(ll)) #list of unnamed matrices, but I would like them separately : A1, A2, ...
```

I would like to return the individual DataFrames separately instead, uniquely named, not bunched together in one list without names, but don't know how:

`return A1, A2, A3`

The function should be flexible enough to batch convert whatever number of arrays is passed into the function, not just 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
   
   def batch_df(l):

       ...

       return ll

   # edit the expected return values
   A1, A2, A3 = batch_df([A1, A2, A3])
```

(i don't really understand your question)

or

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from numpy.random import rand

my_dfs = {}
my_dfs['A1'] = rand(3,3)
my_dfs['A2'] = my_dfs['A1'] * 2
my_dfs['A3'] = my_dfs['A1'] * 3 

labels = ['a','b','c']

#----------#
# Do stuff #
#----------#
def batch_df(d):
    
    # loop over the dataframes
    for k, A in d.items():
        # update the value
        my_dfs[k] = pd.DataFrame(A, index=labels, columns=labels)

     # no need to return --> dictionaries are by reference
        
        
batch_df(my_dfs)
```

res: my_dfs['A1']

```
    a           b           c
a   0.501693    0.506768    0.315132
b   0.382843    0.116506    0.194385
c   0.208627    0.033067    0.121261
```

Comment: `ll` in the question is a list. but inside that list are separate objects. making a function output `ll` by itself gives only one output. I instead would like to output 3 or more objects from the function, unpacked from the contents of `ll`

Comment: but if you provide an equal amount of expected values -->  A1, A2, A3 =  <-- then there is no real issue?

Comment: or that amount is unknown?

Comment: Why don't you use, a dictionary?

Comment: the code before the edits worked fine, i was only replying to your question about not understanding

Comment: thus the --->  A1, A2, A3 = batch_df([A1, A2, A3])  <--- ?

Comment: don't mind to accept an answer if it worked XD